# set Context.User to something in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax

In my application before me one coder added a function to global asax
although it is not called anywhere when I try to PostAuthResponse it calls this 
and  `Request.IsAuthenticated` is return false so my codes give error 
this is error

```
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at ePayment.cc5payment.processorder()
```

This is the global asax code. How do I put a dummy user into `Context.User`

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Context.User = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal =
                new AuthorizationPrincipal(Context.User.Identity);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        GenericIdentity identity = new
                        GenericIdentity("some_user_name","my_authentication");
        Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity, new string[]{});
                                                       //this is a list of roles.
    }
}
```

You should read about the [GenericPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.genericprincipal.aspx) class on msdn.

Comment: Can I use it wiht ***ADFS*** and ***OWIN*** , `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity`?